# configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'BotValues' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So this is the first time, that I cant find a solution for one of my problems online.
I have been trying to revive an old Discord Bot of mine, written in Python, after a lot of troubleshooting this is the last Error I cant solve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bot.py", line 72, in <module>
    bot = bot()
  File "Bot.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.token = config.get('BotValues', 'token')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\configparser.py", line 781, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1149, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'BotValues'
```

As far as I understand it seems to be a missing file in the Installation, so I have tried getting everything up to date a second time, but it didnt change the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is config file not found error, this a configparser bug and not yet fixed, check here https://github.com/jaraco/configparser/issues/53

```
Check the config File is present in the directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your config file. Make sure that you have something like this in it with your token.

```
[BotValues]
token= 'TOKEN_HERE'
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot that solved my problem I have totally overlooked that my file went missing.